# how to make image invisble in first activity when navigating from second activity to first activity

Tags: android

I have two imageviews in `firstActivity(MainActivity)` when i click signIn image then it moves to `SignUp Activity`...
here when i click on signUp image then again it will come to `MainActivity`..and here i have to make `firstName` image invisible..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

ImageView firstName,signIn ;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firstName =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
signIn =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    signIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);              

        }
    });     
    }



 protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart");  

    String mm ="5";
    Intent i= getIntent(); String s = i.getStringExtra("PrevAct");

    if (mm ==s) {               

            firstName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
        }

public class SignUp extends Activity {


ImageView signUp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);      

    signUp =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);       
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
             intent.putExtra("PrevAct","5");
             startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. While you try to launch the MainActivity Activity again, ensure that you re-use the same instance and not a new one for application better performance.

   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
   intent.putExtra("PrevAct","SignUP");
           startActivity(intent);
2. Use a variable to check if the screen is rendered from SignUpActivity.

   Intent i= getIntent();
   String s = i.getExtra("PrevAct","NO");
3. Based on the String Value, you can decide to show/hide.

Please note that `View.Invisible` only hides the view from screen. But still it gets loaded and takes the space on screen. This is a bad UI implementation.

Therefore use `View.GONE` instead.

Your Source Code modified as below

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView firstName,signIn ;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firstName =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    signIn =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        signIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);              

            }
        });     
        }




           protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firstName  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

          { 



            Intent i= getIntent();
            if(i!=null){
            String s = i.getExtra("PrevAct","NO");
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("SignUP"))
            firstName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
else
     firstName.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        }
    }

    public class SignUp extends Activity {

    ImageView signUp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.signup);      

        signUp =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);       
        signUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    intent.putExtra("PrevAct","SignUP");
            startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }}
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); 
     intent.putExtra("PrevAct","5");
     
    
    startActivity(intent);


protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
  
  
  String mm ="5";
  Intent i= getIntent(); String s = i.getStringExtra("PrevAct");
  
  if (mm ==s) {
     
    loginWith.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       signIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
   
  

 }

Comment: thanks for the reply..i have chaged like but not getting..in mainactivity i placed the code in onStop()...

Answer (score 0):

1. By clicking signIn image, use startActivityForResult to start your activity for signing up.
2. In signing up activity, use setResult  and finish to return to login activity.
3. When returning to first activity, make firstName image invisible or gone as you like in onActivityResult.